# Running a training operation inside another training operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to run a small training operation inside another training operation as follows:

```
def get_alphas(weights, filters):
    alphas = tf.Variable(...)
    # Define some loss and training_op here
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for some_epochs:
            sess.run(training_op)
        return tf.convert_to_tensor(sess.run(alphas))

def get_updated_weights(default_weights):
    weights = tf.Variable(default_weights)
    # Some operation on weights to get filters

    # Now, the following will produce errors since weights is not initialized
    alphas = get_alphas(weights, filters)

    # Other option is to initialize it here as follows
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([weights]))
        calculated_filters = sess.run(filters)
        alphas = get_alphas(default_weights, calculated_filters)

    return Some operation on alphas and filters
```

So, what I want to do is to create a Variable by the name of `weights`. `alphas` and `filters` are dynamically dependent (through some training) on `weights`. Now, as `weights` are trained, `filters` will change as it is created through some operations on `weights`, but `alphas` also need to change, which can be found only though another training operation.

I will provide the exact functions, if intention is not clear from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick you describe won't work, because [`tf.Session.close`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/client/session_management#Session.close) releases all associated resources, such as variables, queues, and readers. So the result of `get_alphas` won't be a valid tensor.

The best course of action is to define several losses and training ops (affecting different parts of the graph) and run them within a *single session*, when you need to.

```
alphas = tf.Variable(...)
# Define some loss and training_op here

def get_alphas(sess, weights, filters):
  for some_epochs:
    sess.run(training_op)

# The rest of the training...
```

Comment: Is there any way to integrate the newly created layer into a Keras layer? I know custom layers can be added to Keras models, but now when some part of the graph is to be trained in addition to training the model, how can we make Keras to play nice with that?

Comment: @layog this seems like a new question, not directly related to this one. Please click "Ask Question" and provide all the details, I'll be happy to answer that